# Bluetooth LE disconnect() - Android behavior

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question about Android bluetooth LE disconnect(), which behaves differently, depending on the running scenario.

My application connects to an embedded device which runs the GATT server and the communication is working fine. The device is not bonded, pairing process happens every time i connect to it and i disconnect every time the Android activity is closed or paused.

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mGattUpdateReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
    if (mBluetoothLeService != null)
        mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
    
    }
```

If the connection is idle (no communication forth and back) then disconnect() works fine and i can see the device receiving disconnect event and everything good.
But when i run a timer on the device sending indications with counting value to android every 750 msec, no disconnect happens when the activity is paused/closed. The device keep sending the counter value and receives HVC confirmations for ever. The only way to stop Android to send HVCs is to disable BT adapter on the phone. Killing the application doesn't help.
I saw this answer here [stackoverflow.com/questions/44521828/android-ble-gatt-disconnected-vs-device-disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521828/android-ble-gatt-disconnected-vs-device-disconnected)
which is 4 years old. Are we in the same situation now or did I mess it somehow?

Comment: You haven't published the relevant code (the calls to the BluetoothGatt object), but if you totally kill your app and the Bluetooth connection stays alive, there is a bug in your Android device's Bluetooth stack.

Answer (score 0):

Good point!

Yes on a second device it works as expected. As soon as onPause() is hit disconnect is triggered to the remote device, no matter if communication is ongoing or not.
So nothing wrong with Android but something wrong with BT stack on my first device (SGS8)